# fill input with leading zeros

Tags: javascript, angular8, mask

I'm in trouble but I can't find a correct way to do it. I used the mask = "0000000000", but he didn't answer me. I have an input that allows up to 10 numbers, EX: 1234256896, that is 10 elements. If the user enters 12345, I have to add 5 more zeros to the left, as he needs to complete the 10 numbers, the result would be like this: 0000012345. If the user enters 123, he will have to add 7 more zeros to the left.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement `focusout` event of input tag and `format` value with

TS code

```
format() {
    this.mynumber = this.padLeft(this.mynumber, "0", 10);
  }

  padLeft(text: string, padChar: string, size: number): string {
    return (String(padChar).repeat(size) + text).substr(size * -1, size);
  }
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="mynumber" (focusout)="format()">
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-format-number-leading-0

Answer (score 2):

To get leading zero use array slice() method in javascript.

```
function getNumberWithLeadingZero(number) {
  if (number<=9999999999) {
    number = ("0000000000"+number).slice(-10);
  }
  return number;
}
```

This will return number with leading zero.

```
console.log(getNumberWithLeadingZero(126534));
```

This will return string `"0000126534"`. You can revert back to initial number by using method **parseInt()**

```
 number = parseInt(number)
```