# Formatting number with ngx-mask

Tags: angular, ngx-mask

i try to format number value using ngx-mask pipe.

So input data is: 284 and output should be 000284. and for eg. input 3 should be shown like 000003. did some one now how format for this case should looks like?

Comment: Hope this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61809668/fill-input-with-leading-zeros